# Marklogic How to continue looping after throw catching exception

Tags: marklogic

I would like to know how to continue looping after throwing exception and document fail at total count.

example: fail document 010291.xml at count 4000 and continue loop again.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
try {
  let $uris := cts:uris((),(),
                 cts:and-query(
                   cts:collection-query("/TRA")
                 )
  )[1 to 200000]

  for $uri in $uris
  return    
    if (fn:exists(doc($uri))) then ()
    else $uri,

  xdmp:elapsed-time()
} catch($err) { 
  "received the following exception: ", $err
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to do with this code? You might wanna batch up to allow this to scale..

Comment: I want to know which uri documents are bad in database. I have limit 200k due to time out in qconsole. Not sure how to scan over 3 million documents.

Comment: I'd look at batching up the processing using for instance [taskbot](https://github.com/mblakele/taskbot)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the try-catch statement inside the loop

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $uris := cts:uris((),(),
               cts:and-query(
                 cts:collection-query("/TRA")
               )
)[1 to 200000]

for $uri in $uris
return
  try{(
        if (fn:exists(doc($uri))) 
        then ()   
        else $uri,
        xdmp:elapsed-time()
      )
  } catch($err) { 
    "received the following exception: ", $err
  }
```

Comment: Great! Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely that there is a better way to do whatever you're trying to do with that code, but specifically to complete the iterations in case of an error, you need to apply the try/catch below the `for`, around the call that you expect to throw an exception:

```
let $uris := 
  cts:uris((),'limit=200000',
    cts:and-query(
     cts:collection-query("/TRA")
    ))
for $uri in $uris
let $result :=
  try { fn:exists(doc($uri)) }
  catch($err) { $err }
return
  typeswitch($result)
  case element(error:error) return ("received the following exception: ", $result)
  default return $result
, 
xdmp:elapsed-time()
```

There is some overhead to using try/catch, so you may notice this query slow down as a result of calling it once for every item in the sequence.